# <p> tag obstructing <nav>'s children?

Tags: html, css, z-index

Codepen: http://codepen.io/marcoms/pen/vAgep/

The above pen has a `<nav>`bar with a dropdown list, with the hierarchy:

```
nav > ul.nav-list > li.parent > ul  /* ul: dropdown list */
```

The subsequent `<p>` hides the dropdown, which is unwanted, and I can't figure out how I can stop it.

Oddly, if a `{-webkit-,-moz-,...}transform` is applied then the dropdown stacks itself above the `<p>`. (paste `-webkit-transform: translateX(0)` in the pen and see), which is almost certainly a bug, but I'm not sure what I can do to fix this, aside from changing `display` and `z-index`es.

Comment: The transform thing happened because apparently it creates a stacking context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For `z-index` to work properly, you must also use `position:relative` (or any `position` really, but `relative` in this case)

Comment: Thanks! In fact, just setting `position: relative` fixes it by itself. Any idea why that is?

Comment: @MarcoScannadinari Because otherwise it can't create the stacking context that it needs to work.

Comment: Sorry, I mean without the `z-index` set. Checking computed rules says that `z-index` is set to auto, so does that mean that auto-z-indexed, relative-displayed elements always stack over elements that they cover, even though they are not parents of the covered element?

Comment: OK just tested it on a separate page. Overflowing elements from a parent are obscured by other elements in the page, unless a `position` that is !static is set.